# Vim displays json file without any quotes

Tags: javascript, json, vim

I have a validated json file that will display without any quotes in Vim. The only time it displays the json file correctly is under Visual mode.

I have tried disabling eslint, jshint, youcompleteme

OS X
MacVim 7.4
Vim 7.4 in Terminal

[image]

[image]

Comment: possibly one of your plugins? did you add any new plugins recently?

Comment: `:verbose set conceallevel?`

Comment: Are you using any json plugin? eg https://github.com/elzr/vim-json. could you try opeing vim with `vim -u NONE` ?

Comment: Thank you guys. Your comments lead me down the right path

Comment: Have you found any workaround? The only option I'm aware of now is just to run manually `setlocal conceallevel=0`, when you are editing a json file. Are you aware of anything better?

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov thanks, solved my issue. now i can watch quotes in json files

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The built-in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/json.vim` uses Vim's *conceal feature* to hide the quotes, presumably to remove unnecessary clutter.

You must have enabled concealing by setting the `'conceallevel'` option to `2` or `3`; the default is `0` (off). Likewise, you see the quotes in visual mode because of your `'concealcursor'` setting.

Inside a JSON file, check where the conceal options got set:

```
:verbose set conceallevel? concealcursor?
```

Then, you can adapt your settings to suit your preferences.

Comment: I found the culprit was a plugin named indentLine. It had changed the conceallevel from it's default of 0

Answer (score 31):

Adding to the currently accepted answer, you can disable that behavior specifically for JSON by setting the following option in you `.vimrc`:

```
" Disable quote concealing in JSON files
let g:vim_json_conceal=0
```

That way, you don't have to set `conceallevel` to 0 (disabled), which would also make useful plugins like indentLine (which was mentioned in a comment above) not work anymore.

Comment: I don't think this is the right variable for vim-json plugin. https://github.com/elzr/vim-json/commit/8324ebdd5cf3407e0469b098e1cba5deed642bfb

Comment: This was what helped me

Comment: @user8162 the inbuild json highlighting for vim uses g:vim_json_conceal.

Answer (score 19):

Like already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40604923/7809404), one can check which plugin caused the increased conceal level:

```
:verbose set conceallevel?
```

If the conceal level is caused by the [**vim-json** Plugin](https://github.com/elzr/vim-json):

```
let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal = 0
```

If conceal is caused by the [**indentLine** Plugin](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine):

```
let g:indentLine_setConceal = 0
```

In vimrc, You can add both options for json files:

```
autocmd Filetype json
  \ let g:indentLine_setConceal = 0 |
  \ let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal = 0
```

Comment: if I use `let g:indentLine_setConceal = 0` for the [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine) plugin, it just does not work anymore. A quote from it's Readme: "You can customize these settings, but the plugin will not function if conceallevel is not set to 1 or 2." :(

Comment: @Wolfson & anybody else, setting `let g:indentLine_fileTypeExclude = ['json']` fixes this problem with indentLine

Answer (score 0):

I find this annoying because the lines 'jump' as quotes are hidden and unhidden.

Setting conceallevel=1 replaces the " with space (rather than hiding them) which stops the jumping while still making json more readable.